# Creating a proxy with netcat

Tags: proxy, netcat

I'm trying to setup a permanent proxy server for one of my servers to reroute connections having issues.

The proxy server is running `Centos 7 x86`

User `-UDP or TCP-> Proxy -> Server`

I am am using these commands in an sh file,

```
#!/bin/bash
nc -u -l -p 800 -c "nc -u ********.com 800" &
nc -l -p 800 -c "nc ********.com 800" &
```

The results are high packet loss and slow connections.  Once one person connects/disconnects another is not capable of connecting.

`socat` is not an option as I am having trouble maintaining it on this particular VPS.  It crashes it.

Is this command wrong or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I have given up on this, I'm just going to write my own proxy software, that way I know how it works and that it works.

Comment: regarding disconnects, - nc is stoping after first disconnect, put while true; do 
nc 
nc
done
so it will restart it after first user is disconnected ;)